# how to retrieve multiple properties using @NameLookup in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I am using @NameLookUp formula to retrieve internet address by giving a search key and it is working fine.But now i want to retrive not only the internet address but also some other properties like FirstName and LastName.
Here is the formula i am using to @Namelookup internet address by giving  search string.

```
Vector vec=m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"InternetAddress\")");
```

//username is the String variable(Search Criteria)

Can anyone please help how to retrieve multiple properties(like firstName and lastName along with InternetAddress) by evaluate the formula only once. If it cant be done using @Namelookup is there any other way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example when using evaluate() to call a Formula is not a good idea.
What you want to do is to get the NotesDocument class and read values from it.

Something like this (disclaimer, I am not a Java developer):

```
// Open Domino Directory on specified server
Database db = session.getDatabase("YourServer/Domain", "names.nsf");
// Get a view with user name is sorted first column
View view = db.getView("($Users)");
// Get the person document for specified user
Document doc = view.getDocumentByKey(userName, true);
if (doc != null) {
   // Get text values from Notes document
   String emailAddress = doc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress");
   String officePhone = doc.getItemValueString("OfficeNumber");
   String officeAddress = doc.getItemValueString("OfficeStreetAddress");
}
```

I believe this would be faster than multiple lookups using evaluate(), and you also have the added benefit of full error handling, and all being native code.

Comment: The difference is that @NameLookup searches for specified user name across *all Domino Directories*, not just in default names.nsf. If company has only one Domino Directory names.nsf, your approach works well.

Comment: True. And thanks for fixing my code, Knut. I just copied most of it from Domino Designer help, and missed a few details when I edited it.

Comment: view.getDocumentByKey fetches me a single document.but there can be multiple entries that matches the search criteria..in that case i will get only one document..

Comment: Should normally only be one person with the same name. But if you want to get all documents matching the key, you use the getAllDocumentsByKey method of the NotesView class to get a NotesDocument collection, then loop though the collection using the getFirstDocument/getNextDocument methods.

Answer (score 1):

@NameLookup only returns the value of one item per call.

Assuming your goal is to only have one Evaluate statement, you could chain the calls together and return an array of values in a certain order:

```
Vector vec=m_session.evaluate("FirstName := @NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"FirstName\"); LastName:= @NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"LastName\"); InternetAddress :=@NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"InternetAddress\"); FirstName:LastName:InternetAddress");
```

Or possibly:

```
String firstName = m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"FirstName\")");
String lastName = m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"LastName\")");
String internetAddress = m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([NoUpdate];\""+ userName + "\"; \"InternetAddress\")");
```

And then add those three strings in any order into your Vector.

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry if the question is not clear..what i am looking for is if i retrieve an element for a search criteria i want the corresponding values for the other fields also..for example..if i do NameLookup for X i want X's email Id,FirstName and LastName as one entry..

Comment: I can't think of a single call that would return multiple item values in one object but of course you could build up your own object making multiple calls to @NameLookup and return that from a function if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i tried the way you told but there is no guarantee that multiple NameLookup will retrieve the entries in the same order..

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the DirectoryNavigator class.  I believe it's been available since Notes/Domino 8.5 (perhaps even before that).  DirectoryNavigator uses some of the same core logic as @NameLookup, so it should perform well.

Here's some sample code.  I haven't tested this exact code, but I adapted it from production code that does a similar lookup:

```
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String inetAddress = null;

    Vector<String> lookupItems = new Vector<String>();
    lookupItems.addElement("FirstName");
    lookupItems.addElement("LastName");
    lookupItems.addElement("InternetAddress");

    Vector<String> vName = new Vector<String>();
    vName.addElement(userName);

    Directory dir = session.getDirectory();
    DirectoryNavigator dirNav = dir.lookupNames("($Users)", vName, lookupItems, true);
    if( dirNav != null && dirNav.getCurrentMatches() != 0 ) {

        // Digest the results of the lookup

        Vector<String> value = null;
        value = dirNav.getFirstItemValue();
        firstName = value.elementAt(0);

        value = dirNav.getNextItemValue();
        lastName = value.elementAt(0);

        value = dirNav.getNextItemValue();
        inetAddress = value.elementAt(0);
    }
```